# Running TOR on Centos 6

Tags: centos6.5, tor

I'm the operator of the XMPP server on darkness.su.The server runs on Centos 6.

I installed TOR and configured it to provide a hidden service access to the server.It was working fine at first,but ever since an update a few months ago it started giving me these errors:

```
    799  May 25 14:19:37.060 [warn] Permissions on directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service are too permissive.
  800  May 25 14:19:37.060 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
  801  May 25 14:19:37.060 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I tried to check the logs,but I can't find them,and setting one doesn't seem to work.I've tried removing TOR and wiping all its folder,then reinstalling it.Same thing.

I'm installing through yum from TOR Project's repository.

With chmod 700 on the hidden service directory(owned by TOR):

```
Jul 24 21:39:05.573 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ cannot be read: Permission denied
Jul 24 21:39:05.573 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Jul 24 21:39:05.573 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above
```

After changing directory owner to root:

```
Jul 24 22:11:36.236 [warn] /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ is not owned by this user (_tor, 496) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jul 24 22:11:36.236 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Jul 24 22:11:36.236 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: Now set the owner to the correct user!

Comment: It was correctly set originally and is again,that was just to test a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check three things:

1. The file ownership should be correct.

   If you use Tor from torproject.org, this should be `_tor`. If you use Tor from EPEL or Fedora, this should be `toranon`.

   ```
   chown -R _tor:_tor /var/lib/tor
   ```

   or

   ```
   chown -R toranon:toranon /var/lib/tor
   ```
2. The permissions should be correct.

   The hidden service directory must be readable only by the Tor user.

   ```
   find /var/lib/tor/hidden_service -type d | xargs chmod u+rwx,go=
   find /var/lib/tor/hidden_service -type f | xargs chmod u+rw,go=
   ```
3. SELinux contexts must be set correctly. In recent releases of RHEL/CentOS, Tor has an SELinux policy applied to it.

   To fix broken SELinux labels:

   ```
   restorecon -r -v /var/lib/tor
   ```

Comment: Tried it,but seems to give the same result(permission denied).

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: Did the chown and the SElinux command,as well as permissions (type f says there's a missing operand at the end by the way) and output from TOR doesn't seem to be different..

Comment: Have you actually looked at the ownership and permissions of the directories and files? What are they? Remember that I'm not the NSA and I can't see your screen! You have to be explicit.

Comment: Permissions are 700 all the way down and owner is _tor:_tor as I'm getting it from TOR's repos.

Comment: @Darkness.su Oops. Not sure how I missed your last comment. It's been my experience over several years that the Tor builds distributed by Tor themselves are not well integrated into the operating system. The build in Fedora/EPEL is much better. Though the primary problem with running it is that you may have to wait for updates, since Fedora/EPEL builds go through QA.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely with SELinux. No, I'm not going to say to set it to `permissive` (I hate that default answer).  It has to do with the subdirectory and the context in which the init.d script is executing (I think). You might be able to fix this by creating a real systemd entry, not 100% sure.

I had this issue, and I chose the simple solution which works since I only have 1 hidden service. Not sure if this causes a problem with multiples or not (I suspect it might). Alternatively, you can spend time debugging the context issue.  That would be the best solution, but if you only have one service, you could just:

Change:

```
/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
```

to:

```
/var/lib/tor/
```

and be done.

Comment: I added the tag selinux to this just to see if someone else can give a better answer.